# How to show the Systray Icon and also the corresponding executable in the taskmanager by default when we run the installer using NSIS?

Tags: nsis

My requirement is: When i installed a software using NSIS, once the installation is successfully completed it should show a notification icon (systray icon).

I am able to create the installer with the required dlls, executables and other files. But it is not showing the systray icon automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ExecShell`, `Exec` or `ExecWait` to start a new process:

```
Section
SetOutPath $INSTDIR
File "something\Display.exe"
ExecShell "" "$INSTDIR\Display.exe"
SectionEnd
```

If you are using the Modern UI then you can put a run checkbox on the finish page instead if you want to give the user the option of not running the app:

```
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN "$INSTDIR\Display.exe"
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"

Section
SetOutPath $INSTDIR
File "something\Display.exe"
SectionEnd
```

Comment: Thank you for  the solution. It helped me a lot.